# How do I extract a sub-regex expression based on another regex value in Java?

Tags: java, regex

My requirement is to have a method that passes a regex and a pattern to be matched for a subregex and return all such subregex as list etc.

If I pass regex as `^[0-9]{10}-[0-9a-z]{2}.[a-z]{5}$`

**Case 1**

```
method1(regex, patternToMatch)
```

I should be getting values as `{10}`, `{2}` and `{5}` in list.

i.e, Extract each substring inside {} in regex.

**Case2**

```
method1(regex, patternToMatch)
```

I should be getting values as `[0-9]`, `[0-9a-z]`, `[a-z]` in list.

i.e, Extract each substring inside [] in regex.

I am not very much familiar with Pattern and Regex in java.

Please help me implementing this.

Thanks a tons for help!

Comment: You probably want to use [groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg).

Comment: It seems like you want to decompose the regex into its tokens... May I ask why?

Comment: @Mena -  Please could you help me with the implementation for atleast 1 method?

Comment: @fge - As my project need, I need to count the num of occurence of a character in different positions.

Comment: So you want a method that returns an array or arraylist containing the strings `10`, `2`, and `5`?

Comment: This looks like a XY problem. What do you mean by "count the num of occurrence of a character in different positions"?

Comment: And what do you mean by "subregex"?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat - Just like we have substring I named it subregex :) And Yes, even if I can get 10, 2, 5 it will satisfy my req now.

Comment: @fge - Sorry I cant explain the reason why I need this for my project. But I need it. Else will have to parse whole regex looking for { and } curly braces and extract number from within. :(

Comment: If one of the answers here satisfactorily solves your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. For more information, see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

not sure how to do this in java but in general you will be using regex like `({\d+})/g` for getting all the values in the curly braces {10}, {2} and {5}

and similarly you will be using `(\[.*?\])/g` for getting [0-9], [0-9a-z], [a-z].

Online demo here : http://regex101.com/r/mO1kE5

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program that will do that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.*;

/**
 * @author Randy Carlson 
 * @version 3/6/14
 */
public class MetaRegex
{
    /**
     * Main method.
     * 
     * @param args The command-line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String regexToMatch = "^[0-9]{10}-[0-9a-z]{2}.[a-z]{5}$"; //the sting you want to find matches in

        List<String> quantifierNumbers = method1("(?<=\\{).*?(?=})", regexToMatch); //creates an ArrayList containing all the numbers enclosed within {}
        List<String> charClassContents = method1("(?<=\\[).*?(?=])", regexToMatch); //creates an ArrayList containing all the characters enclosed within []

        //The rest of this just prints out the ArrayLists
        System.out.println("Numbers contained in {}:");
        for(String string : quantifierNumbers)
        {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Contents of []:");
        for(String string : charClassContents)
        {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets a list of all of the matches of a given regex in a given string.
     * 
     * @param regex The regex to match against {@code patternToMatch}
     * @param patternToMatch The pattern to find matches in.
     * @return An {@code ArrayList<String>}
     */
    static List<String> method1(String regex, String patternToMatch)
    {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList(); //creates an ArrayList to contain the matches
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); //turns the regex from a string into something that can actually be used
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(patternToMatch); //creates a Matcher that will find matches in the given string, using the above regex
        while(matcher.find()) //loops while the matcher can still find matches
        {
            output.add(matcher.group()); //adds the match to the ArrayList
        }

        return output; //returns the ArrayList of matches
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Numbers contained in {}:
> 10
> 2
> 5
>
> Contents of []:
> 0-9
> 0-9a-z
> a-z
> ```